# Make new instace from MySql Class in Program.cs

Tags: c#, mysql, static

i wrote a class library for MySql connection and i added that dll file to my project.
     I should use it from every where so i need to define it and make instance just for one time.
     So i wrote it to Program.cs but it throwed the this exception which is down. I couldnt find why.
     Thanks for your help.

[Program.cs]

```
using MySqlFramework;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Kutuphane_Otomasyon
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static MySQL mysql; 
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        mysql = new MySQL("localhost", "kutuphane", "root", "");
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

MySql Connection Library Class [Failed here]

Here is the image of my mysql dll source codes. And error occourred here.

[image]

Comment: The issue is your connection string - you're passing an invalid parameter. Can you post the stack trace and/or full connection string? That would help.

Comment: much easier if you post the text of the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I can see is you are passing a parameter `MultipleActiveResultSets`, but as far as I know that parameter is not supported in MySQL connection strings.

Try removing that parameter from the connection string you are passing in your MySQL class constructor and see if that removes the issue (it should).